# getting java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed during sslSocket.startHandshake();

Tags: ssl, jetty, httpsurlconnection

I am getting the exception at client side, even though I set all the properties of the keystore like protocol, keystoretyoe, password everything at client side when I try to access the url using httpsurlconnection.

But If I trustAll, setNeedClientAuth(false), then it is working properly.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

What could be wrong in my prog?
Any help is appreciated
Thx
GK

Comment: Could you post your code sample?

Comment: Could you also post A full stacktrace of what you are seeing as well?